# Android: ConstraintLayout laying out 4 buttons in 2 groups not equally distributed

Tags: android

How to constraint 4 buttons grouped in 2 groups on ConstraintLayout to achieve something similar as on the image below?

This two groups of buttons must be align to left/right appropriately with some additional padding.

[image]

Comment: I think using a `RelativeLayout` would be more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Maybe you are right but I have also other elements that lays out using Constraint Layout. It is something like Gamepad Controller emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply constrain the leftmost and rightmost buttons to the parent's edge, and constrain the inner buttons against the outer buttons.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#eee">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="L1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="L2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/l1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="R1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/r2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="R2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah you are right :) Now I think that my question was stupid :) It was so easy to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

Use  widget to separate two groups of button in constraint layout. GuideLine is based on percentage.